# Ассемблер -I/O

Tags: ассемблер, x86

Разработать exe-программу ввода строковых данных с клавиатуры. Ввести с клавиатуры 3 строки и вывести их через одну на ассемблере.

```
.model small
.data
msg1    db 13,10,'Input string: $'
msg2    db 13,10,'Result: $'
msg3    db 13,10,'Result2: $'
buf db 200,201 dup(0)   ;принимает строку, введенную с клавиатуры
ent db 10,13,'$'
y db 0
.stack 256
.code
start:
mov ax,@data    ;Настраиваем сегментные регистры
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov y,0
mov ah,9        ;функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx,msg1     ;выводимое сообщение
int 21h         ;выводим на экран
mov ah,0ah      ;функция ввода строки с клавиатуры
mov dx,offset buf       ;буфер куда вводить
int 21h         ;пользователь вводит в текст в buf
xor bp,bp   ;кол-во символов
xor sp,sp   ;кол-во замен
lea si,buf[2]       ;источник - начало введенного тексата
lea di,buf[2]       ;приемник - начало введенного тексата
jmp lp
m3: inc sp      ;тут должен быть счетчик
jmp skip
lp: lodsb           ;взять очередной символ
cmp al,13       ;если конец строки
jz fin          ;то закончить
cmp al,' '      ;если пробел
jz m3           ;то пропустить
cmp al,'0'  ; код меньше 0
jb m2       ;то пропускаем
cmp al,'9'
ja m2   
inc bp      ;тут должен быть счетчик
m2: cmp al,'a'      ;если это не буква а
jnz m1          ;то пропустить
mov al,'A'      ;а->A
inc sp
m1: stosb           ;если не пробел то сохранить прочитанный символ
skip:   jmp lp          ;продолжить цикл
fin:    mov al,'$'      
stosb           ;установить символ конца строки
mov ah,9        ;функция вывода сообщения на экран
lea dx,msg2     ;выводимое сообщение
int 21h         ;выводим на экран
lea dx,buf[2]       ;выводимое сообщение
int 21h         ;выводим на экран
lea dx,msg2     ;выводимое сообщение
int 21h         ;выводим на экран
mov ax,bp
call print
mov ah,9        ;функция вывода сообщения на экран  
lea dx,msg3     ;выводимое сообщение
int 21h         ;выводим на экран
mov ax,sp
call print
mov ah,1    ;Ожидаем нажатия любой клавиши
int 21h
mov ax,4c00h    ;закончить программу
int 21h
print proc
;преобразование числа из ах в десятичную строку и вывод на экран
;ax - число
mov bx,10   ;основание системы
xor cx,cx   ;в сх будет количество цифр в десятичном числе
xor dx,dx   ;очистить старшую часть делимого
div bx      ;делим число на степени 10
push dx     ;и сохраняем остаток от деления(коэффициенты при степенях) в стек
inc cx      ;увеличиваем количество десятичных цифр числа
test ax,ax  ;после деления остался 0?
jnz @@m1a   ;если нет, продолжаем
mov ah,2        ;ф-я вывода символа
pop dx      ;взять из стека цифру цисла
add dl,'0'  ;преобразовываем цифру в ASCII символ
int 21h     ;вывести на экран
loop @@m2a  ;все цифры
ret
print endp
end start
```

Comment: и побыстрее ?

---

@рол, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: .model small
.data
msg1 db 13,10,'Input string: $'
msg2 db 13,10,'Result: $'
msg3 db 13,10,'Result2: $'
buf db 200,201 dup(0) ;принимает строку, введенную с клавиатуры
ent db 10,13,'$'
y db 0
.stack 256
.code

start:
 mov ax,@data ;Настраиваем сегментные регистры
 mov ds,ax
 mov es,ax
  mov y,0
 mov ah,9  ;функция вывода сообщения на экран
 lea dx,msg1  ;выводимое сообщение
 int 21h   ;выводим на экран
 mov ah,0ah  ;функция ввода строки с клавиатуры
 mov dx,offset buf       ;буфер куда вводить

 int 21h   ;пользователь вводит в текст в buf
 xor bp,bp ;кол-во символов

Comment: в вопрос добавьте и код оформите

Comment: осталось добавить фразу со знаком вопроса в конец